# OpenLayers v6.3.1 distance between two locations

Tags: openlayers, distance

- On their [API](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_sphere.html#.getDistance) there is a function called getDistance(), when I use this function with two points/locations it shows a notifications that says function not recognized.

Any idea how to cover this within OpenLayers 6.1.3

Comment: How are you using it?, what coordinate system are you using?, can you post your code?

Answer (score 1):

If your coordinates are LonLat the simplest method is

```
var distance = ol.sphere.getDistance([loc1.long, loc1.lat], [loc2.long, lat2.lat]) / 1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I was able to find the distance with two other functions: 
1. [LineString()](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_geom_LineString-LineString.html)
2. [getLength()](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_sphere.html#.getLength)

First create two locations:

```
var location_1 = ol.proj.fromLonLat([loc1.long, loc1.lat]);
var location_2 = ol.proj.fromLonLat([loc2.long, lat2.lat]);
```

Secondly create a line between these two points:

```
 var line = new ol.geom.LineString([location_1 , location_2]);
```

Than convert the length of the line to km:

```
 var distance = Math.round(line.getLength()  / 1000 * 100) / 1000;
```

The **distance** gives you the real distance in km between two locations.

Comment: `line.getLength()` does NOT give the real distance, it gives the distance in projection units which is only true at the equator - at  60 degrees latitude it would give twice  the real distance.  For the real disatnce you need use `ol/sphere.getLength` as used in the example https://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/measure.html